# Setting the background color when plotting in GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, color, matplotlib, plot

I am wondering if there is an easy way in **GeoPandas** to change the background color of a plotted map. Here is my code; I can't figure out how to change the white background color to any other color. The important part here is to change the background color of the "**map**" portion and not the legend portion.

```py
ax = osm.plot(
    figsize=(8,8),
    column='building',
    cmap='tab20',
    legend=True,
    legend_kwds={"loc": "upper left", "bbox_to_anchor": (1, 1),'frameon':False}
    )
ax.set_title(f'Buldings in {address}')
ax.axis('off');
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know the first thing about geopandas, but some quick googling suggests that you could use:  `ax.set_facecolor('red')`.  Does this work for you?

Comment: Did my answer work? [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

One way is to create a box covering the dataframes extent and plot this below your df using zorder:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import box
df = gpd.read_file(r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\45buildings.geojson")

ax = df.plot(figsize=(8,8), column='objekttypnr', cmap='tab20', legend=True, zorder=1)

xMin, yMin, xMax, yMax = df.total_bounds
box = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[box(xMin, yMin, xMax, yMax)], crs=df.crs)
box.plot(ax=ax, color="black", zorder=0)
```

[image]